# If Statement & Countif combined

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

in column B I have "CM" in a range =COUNTIF(B:B,"CM") will return the total count of all cells that contain "CM"

I need to take it one more step. where column B contains CM I need to count the range in column H only if the range in H has data/text

Thanks 
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your formula to a `COUNTIFS` which takes multiple parameter sets and use the second parameter set to test if column H has no value/text

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"CM",H:H,"<>")
```

Note, this doesn't exclude the possibility that cells in column H may contain a formula.  That's a question I can't answer.

I'm not sure if you wanted to count cells in column B that **equal** "CM" or **contain** "CM".  Your formula will count any cells that equal upper or lower case "cm" (or any combination thereof). If you really want cells **containing** "CM", wrap it in asterisks

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"*CM*",H:H,"<>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"CM", H:H, "*")
```